# Chef-Server 12 down by bookshelf, oc_bifrost & rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, chef-infra, google-compute-engine

For a couple of days gettin' this errors in logs & services's down (chef-server 12 on GCE vm). Reconfigure make things work, but it lost all my data (restored VM from snapshot).

```
$ chef-server-ctl tail bookshelf

2015-02-18_13:25:39.27064 Usage: bookshelf {start|stop|restart|reboot|ping|console|console_clean|attach}
2015-02-18_13:25:40.28091 Usage: bookshelf {start|stop|restart|reboot|ping|console|console_clean|attach}
2015-02-18_13:25:41.30147 Usage: bookshelf {start|stop|restart|reboot|ping|console|console_clean|attach}

$ chef-server-ctl tail oc_bifrost 

2015-02-18_13:25:38.22431 env: /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/bin/oc_bifrost: Permission denied
2015-02-18_13:25:39.23871 env: /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/bin/oc_bifrost: Permission denied
2015-02-18_13:25:40.24395 env: /opt/opscode/embedded/service/oc_bifrost/bin/oc_bifrost: Permission denied

$ chef-server-ctl tail rabbitmq

2015-02-18_13:25:33.38800 mkdir: cannot create directory `/opt/opscode/embedded/service/rabbitmq/sbin/../var': Permission denied
2015-02-18_13:25:34.49951 mkdir: cannot create directory `/opt/opscode/embedded/service/rabbitmq/sbin/../var': Permission denied
2015-02-18_13:25:35.51375 mkdir: cannot create directory `/opt/opscode/embedded/service/rabbitmq/sbin/../var': Permission denied
```

Nothing has changed for ages.. What's wrong with it? Tnx in advance.

Comment: Don't know the root cause but 'chef-server-ctl upgrade' solved this issue for me while retaining my data.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when upgrading to 12.0.4 from 12.0.0.

You need to make sure you have run the upgrade script which will reconfigure your local instance.

```
chef-server-ctl upgrade
```

If, when you run this, it asks about upgrading from Chef Server 11, then you have not cleaned up a prior migration from 11 to 12. You will need to remove or rename /etc/chef-server

```
mv /etc/chef-server /etc/chef-server.old
```

Then you will see the chef-server being reconfigured and when complete, run:

```
chef-server-ctl start
```

Answer (score 1):

Second point of data for `chef-server-ctl upgrade` plus troubleshooting notes.

WARNING: My org and users etc. were preserved, but your results may vary.

I suspect what happened was that the chef-server-core package got updated. (a careless apt-get upgrade could do it, I noticed it after a crash and reboot.) I shouldn't use the passive voice, but I certainly don't remember doing that.

My troubleshooting steps for posterity.

```
sudo chef-server-ctl stop
sudo chef-server-ctl start
sudo chef-server-ctl tail
```

I see this repeatedly

```
==> /var/log/opscode/rabbitmq/current <==
2015-08-23_23:51:22 mkdir: cannot create directory '/opt/opscode/embedded/service/rabbitmq/sbin/../var': Permission denied
```

Which is weird. That ".." in the path is a clue pointing to a config change between software versions. Maybe the chef deb package got upgraded by mistake and configuration needs to be updated to match (recall chef server is like a dozen services working together)

```
sudo chef-server-ctl upgrade
```

Now my tests pass and my clients can connect, I can get results from

```
knife status
```

Comment: I also encountered the issue after doing `apt-get dist-upgrade` upgraded `chef-server-core`. I guess this has taught me that I should run `sudo chef-server-ctl upgrade` before I run `apt-get`.